# How do I disable dragging one cell over another in JointJS

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, drawing, jointjs

At the moment I can put one cell over another like so:
[image]

I want to prevent the user from dragging one cell over another.
Preferably, when the cell is being dragged over another cell, it should stay on the boundaries of the 'beneath' element. 
Expected behaviour:

[image]
[image]

I checked the API but I couldn't find the solution to my problem.
However, I might have been looking in the wrong sections.